# angularjs core is(type) equals-operator == instead of === i

Tags: angularjs

I'm peeping into angular source
and I run into this code

```
function isObject(value){return value != null && typeof value == 'object';}
```

I'm wondering if there is a reason because of the use == instead of ===

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it really doesn't matter. typeof will return a string, no matter what

> The identically equal and not identically equal operators do the same thing as equal and not equal, except that they do not convert operands before testing for equality.

**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof 
[JavaScript for professional Webdevelopers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026691)

I personally see no reason for using Angulars method instead of typeof, though. Sure, it prevents a false check result if the value is `null`, but do we need another method for this?
Maybe someone can enlighten me.

Comment: mdc check like typeof {a:1} === 'object';

Comment: typeof will return a string, no matter what

Answer (score 0):

By using = you assign a value to something.

```
x = 1 // x now equals 1
x = 2 // x now equals 2
```

By using == you check if something is equal to something else. NOTE: This is not strict.

```
x == 1 // is x equal to 1? (False)
x == 2 // is x equal to 2? (True)
```

By using === you check if something is equal to something else. NOTE: This is strict.

```
x === 1 //is x equal to 1? (False)
x === 2 //is x equal to 2? (True
```

Strict is that it checks not only the equality of the two values, it compares the types of the two values too.  I hope this helps.